# Search cellphone in facebook API

Tags: python, facebook

I'm trying to make a search with a cell phone number in facebook, I try first with requests & urllib but this does not work, next, i try with the Facebook API, but this does not work either, I use python, and this input's in the Python line:

```
facebook.GraphAPI('token').request('search', {'q': 'cellphonenumber', 'type': 'user'})
```

And too with:

```
requests.get("https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=token&q=cellphonenumber&type=user")
```

And...

```
facebook.GraphAPI('token').get_object('search?q=cellphonenumber&type=user')
```

And another code that, again, does not work...

The output of some of this entries are:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/facebook/**init**.py",
>   line 115, in get_object   File
>   "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/facebook/**init**.py", line 293, in
>   request facebook.GraphAPIError: (#200) Application does not have the
>   capability to make this API call

Or

> Response [403]. (in a case of requests use.)

Or

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/facebook/**init**.py",
>   line 115, in get_object   File
>   "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/facebook/**init**.py", line 293, in
>   request facebook.GraphAPIError: An unknown error has occurred.

Some idea? I really need this...

P.D: In all code, I put "token" instead of my token.

Comment: You can not search for users by phone number.

Comment: Why i can search a cell phone number then?

Comment: I don’t know, because so far you are the only person that says this was possible. But then on the other hand you have not really explained what you actually mean by that, so ...

Comment: I do input a cell phone number in facebook, in the browser, and this return me the person asociated to the number. My idea is only do this, but in a python script. I before try without the token (I did not know they were tokens) and the return of the search was "no results for you search", this in the script, and in the copy paste in a browser without account logged in, but in a logged session i do.

Comment: See, that explains it - you are confusing the search you have available via the UI, with the Graph API search. Those two have little to do with each other, and the latter is severely limited (to the few options the documentation lists.) Facebook is deliberately not exposing the powerful search capabilities you have available via the UI, via API.